# How to remove brackets '[ ]'from string using python?

Tags: python, string, slice, strip

I am unable to remove brackets `'[ ]'` from the below string.

I am getting this response through an API:

```
[["b", "m", "l", "a", "p", "c"], [["20,5,93767,TEST,Watch,16"], ["19,5,767, TEST,Lamb,23"], ["19,5,3767,TEST,DB,99"]]]
```

I have to change this response to:

```
"b", "m", "l", "a", "p", "c", "20,5,93767,TEST,Watch,16", "19,5,767, TEST,Lamb,23", "19,5,3767,TEST,DB,99"
```

I have to use python

I am using this code to remove it:

```
(str(content_line)[1:-1])
```

now I am getting this output:

```
"\"b', 'm', 'l', 'a', 'p', 'c\",'\"\\'20,5,93767,TEST,Watch,16\\'\", \"\\'19,5,767, TEST,Lamb,23, \"\\'19,5,3767,TEST,DB,99\\'\"'"
```

Comment: This looks more like a list of lists of strings.
If it truely is a string, you could just try `str.replace("[", "")` and `str.replace("]", "")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
def flatten(content_line):
    result = []
    for element in content_line:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            result.extend(flatten(element))
        else:
            result.append(element)
    return result

flatten(content_line)
```

Comment: Could you add some simple explanation about what exactly this code snippet is doing?

Comment: it's a recursive function that flatten a python list. If a list contains another list, it will recursively flatten that list and return a simple list back.

Comment: Yes. This is the most useful to me as I am also getting a list. Still my output is not what I wanted. Its lookin like this now: ["b", "m", "l", "a", "p", "c", "20,5,93767,TEST,Watch,16", "19,5,767, TEST,Lamb,23", "19,5,3767,TEST,DB,99"]

Comment: if you want a string output instead, you can use `', '.join(flatten(content_line))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str.join` for this

`print(', '.join(content_line))`

Answer (score 1):

```py
# input string
a_st = """ [["b", "m", "l", "a", "p", "c"], [["20,5,93767,TEST,Watch,16"], ["19,5,767, TEST,Lamb,23"], ["19,5,3767,TEST,DB,99"]]] """

# replace brackets '[]' with ''
output = a_st.replace('[','').replace(']','')

# output
print(output)
>>> '"b", "m", "l", "a", "p", "c", "20,5,93767,TEST,Watch,16", "19,5,767, TEST,Lamb,
23", "19,5,3767,TEST,DB,99"'
```

Comment: Thanks, this might work for string, but mine is a list

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using String instead of tuples.

Comment: Could you explain how?